# React material design onclick list-item highlight the item/ active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have 2 panels with a list group on each panel. I am using material design.

**Issue:** 
onclick first list-item on panel 1 it is not getting selected and changing `style = "success"` or highlighting the selected list, same for the panel 2.

Looking for the solution: onclick on list-item it should change the style or active or change the background color. Highlight the selected item and remove it when clicking on another item on the respective panel.

[original code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rtquev)

I want output like this [Bootstrap code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k8yvpw). This was done in bootstrap but looking for a solution in material UI

Comment: ListItem has a property 'selected'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the following lines

In cards

`selected={card==selectedCard}`

in item

`selected={item==selectedCheck}`

I believe it should work after this.

Comment: You can add classes to your selected item by adding another line like 

              `classes={{ selected: "my-class" }}` this will add `my-class` as a class when item is selected, and then in your styles you can have a background color. If you will have to make the css specific enough to override material ui classes.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rtquev-8ragg2 I have added !important to class but you can make the css rule more specific by adding more classes.